# User attributes accessible when using OpenID

Tags: openid

I have used OpenId to authenticate the users of my application. What are the user attributes that I have access to?

Comment: who is your provider? it's provider dependent. For example here are attributes supported by Google and Yahoo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17281022/do-the-google-and-yahoo-implementations-of-openid-respect-the-required-attribu/17281459#17281459

Comment: Google is my provider. Thank you ! That answers my question.